# Trouble with testing angularjs service with jasmine and multiple dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service with quite a few dependencies defined as:

```
angular.module('serversync.services', ['database', 'date-time-format', 'serversync.config'])

.factory('ServerSync', function($log, $q, $http, _, DatabaseProvider, DateTimeFormatter, ExternalSyncServerConfig) {
    var self = this;

    var self.syncSomething = function() {
       ...
    };
    return self;

});
```

(DatabaseProvider, DateTimeFormatter, ExternalSyncServerConfig are other custom services in my app).

I have defined a basic test as follows:

```
describe('ServerSync Tests', function () {

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('database', []);
    module('date-time-format', []);
    module('serversync.config', []);
    module('serversync.services')
  });

  var ServerSyncSvc;
  var log, q, http, underscore;
  var DatabaseProviderSvc, DateTimeFormatterSvc, ExternalSyncServerConfigSvc;

  beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function($log, 
                    $q, 
                    $httpBackend, 
                    DatabaseProvider, 
                    DateTimeFormatter, 
                    ExternalSyncServerConfig, 
                    ServerSync) {
      ServerSyncSvc = ServerSync;
      log = $log;
      q = $q;
      http = $httpBackend;
      underscore = _;
      DatabaseProviderSvc = DatabaseProvider;
      DateTimeFormatterSvc = DateTimeFormatter;
      ExternalSyncServerConfigSvc = ExternalSyncServerConfig;
    });
  });

  it('should have a syncJourney function defined', function () {
    expect(ServerSyncSvc.syncSomething).toBeDefined();
  });

})
;
```

I've used [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/) to try and get up and running but am having no success.
When I run `grunt karma` I get the error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) Service DTW should have a function to be defined FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at assertArg (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1580)
        at assertArgFn (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1591)
        at annotate (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3471)
        at ~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2147
        at invoke (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4163)
        at ~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4104
        at forEach (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323)
        at loadModules (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4123)
        at createInjector (~/myApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4007)
```

I know my Jasmine conf is correct as I can run some tests on simple services that don't have any dependencies.
This whole unit testing thing for angular is a bit new to me and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the concepts of mocking dependencies so I'm hoping it's something simple but I have no idea where to go next to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

In the setup beforeEach - change the modules that are dependencies to `angular.module` instead of just `module`.

```
angular.module('database', []);
angular.module('date-time-format', []);
angular.module('serversync.config', []);
module('serversync.services')
```

module is used for whichever component you are testing (it is a shortcut to the mocks version angular.mock.module). The dependencies should be registered as regular angular modules.

This will probably fix it enough for your "to be defined" unit test to run. However, once you get to actually exercising the code that uses those dependencies you are going to have to provide mocks for the functions within the dependencies. If you are anything like I was, that will bring a slew of more questions.